# Call react native component from android activity

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using expo with react native and i detached the expo application. Now i have an activity in android, what is called when the user select "share a photo" in the cellphone, and select my application. All is nice until here. The activity is called BUT i need to redirect or call a component of my expo react native application (staying in an activity in android and redirecting to the react native compontent). How can i do it ? I really don't find many resources and the few examples tha i've found doesn't run.